# Laravel task shedule

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

How do I schedule a task in Task Scheduler for every 10 minutes on given date and given time.

This code not working

```
$schedule->call(function () {
   (new Studentdata())->studentDataToUpload();  //call your function
})->monthly()->everyTenMinutes()->between('12:30', '15:30');
```

another

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    (new Studentdata())->studentDataToUpload();  //call your function
})->monthlyOn(1, '10:00')->everyTenMinutes();
```

Comment: Do you have an error when you execute it ?

Comment: Do you have the cron-job set up?

Comment: @brombeer yes...

Comment: Another working like daily, monthlyOn, everyTenMinutes, ....but i want to run on start of month at particular time for every ten min, pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron on job scheduler.

Here is a example

```
$schedule->command('send:notification')->cron('0 0 01 * *');
```

This will run on first day of month and for every 10 Min period Run Like Below

```
$schedule->command('send:notification')->cron('0 /10 01 * *');
```

For range use this (*/10 10-13 1 * *)

Comment: Thanks. but i want to run on first day of month at given time. it will run at 00:00 but i want   at 10:00 to 13:00 for every 10 min

Comment: @AnkkitMishrra then this will fit your job (*/10 13 1 * *) use this link to test your cron time https://crontab.guru/#*/10_13_1_*_*

Comment: @AnkkitMishrra okay you can use the range then (*/10 10-13 1 * *) . i have updated the answer too.

Comment: You should vote and accept it as answer then :)